# Why are all my tkinter optionmenus being updated when I change the values of one menu?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, pydev, optionmenu

All my option menu widgets are being updated together when I change the values of 1 option menu.

This is what I use to make all of the menus (`self.var` is initialized as `self.var = StringVar(master)`):

```
def makeMenu(self, name, items, r, c):

    self.var.set(items[0])
    name = OptionMenu(self, self.var, *items)
    name.grid(row = r, column = c , padx = self.pad_x, pady = self.pad_y)
    name.config( width = self.menu_width)
    name.menu = Menu(name, tearoff = self.tear_off)

    for i in range(len(items)):
        name.menu.add_command(label = items[i])  

    return name
```

When I try to make a new menu and change the items, all of the other menus' items change to the new ones as well.

i.e. when I do this:

```
self.layout_menu = self.makeMenu("layout_menu", self.layout_sections, 
                                 self.layout_menu_row, self.layout_menu_col)
```

Comment: Can I see the rest of the code?

Comment: It's a lot code. lol Do you mind specifying? So I have a class for my Tk() window. "var" is initialized as shown above. I have that makeMenu function with those params within my class. My createWidgets function, no params, calls makeMenu to make the default menu using self.layout_menu = self.makeMenu("layout_menu", self.layout_sections, self.row_count, self.col_count). So what i'm trying to do is when the user clicks on an item from a listbox, these menus get updated with corresponding values. When I try to update one with a value, all menus get updated with that value

Comment: @E. Oregel: When Stiffy2000 is asking to see more code I believe he is referring to [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to be able to test the code to see the overall problem.

Comment: I really do not think that you need `StringVar(master)`, you just need `StringVar()`

Comment: @Stiffy2000 I was working on getting you the rest. Your solution works however! All menus were holding the same menu options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really do not think that you need `StringVar(master)`, you just need `StringVar()`

Comment: What happened was it was creating one var[0] for all of my menu's which meant that they were all basically controlled by one variable so anytime one menu changed, the others changed too.